# Do the electrons still collapse to a particle state through double slits if the "observing" instrument is merely listening?

Tags: double-slit-experiment

I know it we cant hear the electrons state (can we?) but from a part philosophical part scientific curiosity I'm fascinated- has anyone even tried this counter intuitive idea?

Answer (score 1):

This is a misconception that I see a lot. A observer in the case of wavefunction collapse does not mean a sensor or person that sees or hears (somehow) a particle.

> "In physics, we use the word "observer" to describe a physical system
> or "agent" that is able to perceive the information about some
> observables (time-dependent dynamical variables that describe the
> state of the physical systems) and, if possible, process them. Most
> often, we want the observers to be able to remember the information,
> send it somewhere, and/or verify the laws of physics that claim to say
> something about the patterns relating different observations."
> An observer of a particular observable, for example the number N of
> photons in a box dV, is simply someone for whom the proposition
> (equation) N=ni has (or will have) a well-defined truth value. That's
> everything I need. The observable has a well-defined truth value
> because – and I hope you won't be surprised – the observer has
> observed the observable." ([source](http://motls.blogspot.com/2013/01/quantum-physics-doesnt-depend-on.html))

The article above is interesting and I highly recommend reading it. I don't know how you would "hear" electrons, but if you could hear them, it would still be an observation, and the wavefunction would collapse.

Comment: Bryan, I agree with Jimmy. Hearing isn't all that different to seeing anyway. Your ears detect waves, and so do your eyes. Bats and dolphins are thought to "see" using sound to build a picture in their heads. So IMHO there's no real difference between seeing and hearing electrons. Both are observations in the wider sense, both involve detection, that detection requires an interaction, and that's when people talk about wavefunction collapse.

Comment: Thankyou both so much. So essentially, the wave function collapse always happens if the data is measured regardless of the input form? It's just everything I read about these experiments are based on photographic evidence it seems, so it led me to wonder if a more "discreet" input had been tried. Maybe we can't hear electrons but imagine if they put a "mic" there anyway and the wave collapses anyway. It could lead to new instrument science.  The results/patterns  through these slits always seem to be a 2 dimensional display. Have they tried measuring the electrons movement in 3d yet?

Comment: @BryanDuke What do your mean by in 3D.  The pattern left on the screen will be 2D.